# Node.js(express) .end() with JSONP

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsonp

I have a function like

```
User.prototype._send = function(type, code, message, callback) {
    if(!message && typeof code != 'number') {
        callback = message;
        message = code;
        code = 200;
    }

    if(typeof message != 'string')
        message = JSON.stringify(message);

    if(type == 'connection' && this.connection) {
        this.connection.writeHead(code || 200, {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': message.length
        });
        this.connection.end(message);
    } else {
        if(!this.listeners.length)
            return this.message_queue.push(arguments);

        var cx = this.listeners.slice(), conn;
        this.listeners = [];
        while(conn = cx.shift()) {
            conn.writeHead(code || 200, {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Content-Length': message.length
            });
            conn.end(message);
        }
        if(callback) callback();
    }
};
```

It returns JSON to the client now. But I want it to return JSONP. I did a lot of research and tried to replace `.end` with `.jsonp` but it does not work.

Comment: http://rambleabouttech.blogspot.com/2012/08/jquery-json-vs-jsonp-using-nodejs.html

Comment: I don't understand is this browser-side or node.js. How is jquery involved here. There is a `.jsonp` response in express, but not in native node.js. You don't need to set headers when using express `.jsonp`. Also for jsonp `Content-Type` must be `application/javascript`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSONP("JSON with padding") is a communication technique and is not an another object notation.
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP for more details.

Basically your application need to accept the query parameter `jsonp` and wrap the json message with that parameter or callback as shown below

```
var jsonpCallback = req.query.jsonp; //Assuming you are using express

message = JSON.stringify(message);

message = jsonpCallback + "(" + message + ");"
```

Comment: Usually the query parameter is named `callback` not `jsonp`, but it doesn't really matter as long as it is properly documented.

Answer (score 1):

As user2840784 points out, you need the callback for this to work. To elaborate on their answer, the client library will need to specify a 'client side callback' when making the request for example:

```
http://my-service.com/get-data.json?callback=callThisFunction
```

If you're using jQuery on the client side, jQuery will provide the callback name for you when you make the `$.ajax` request, so your request will look like:

```
http://my-service.com/get-data.json?callback=jQuery123456789
```

Behind the scenes, jQuery secretly creates a function with the name `jQuery123456789` (or something) to handle your data when it's loadded.

**What you have to do** is make sure you wrap your JSON output with the callback function name, so if your response JSON *would* look like this:

```
{"a":1, "b":2}
```

... then you need to wrap it so it looks like this:

```
jQuery123456789('{"a":1, "b":2}')
```

Again, as user2840784 pointed out, you can get the name of the callback from `req.query.jsonp`.

Hth,
Aaron